# Automatically send Cypress test reports, screenshots and videos to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, testing, automated-tests, cypress

We have developed our own Cypress Dashboard as a part of our diploma thesis and have successfully set it up. However, we are facing a challenge in automating the process of sending the generated test reports, screenshots, and videos to our MongoDB database after a Cypress test is run by a user.

We would like to know if there is a way to accomplish this and if so, what are the steps involved in the process.

We would highly appreciate any suggestions or solutions to this issue.